# Backbone View Design

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to create a html page like this

> ```
> Publisher (Master) - Use CompositeView
>
> Book List (Detail) - User ItemView
>
> Video List (Detail) - ????? 1. What to use for this detail  ?????
> ```

2. Should I get all the data at once request or separate into 3 requests?

> ```
> ABC Publisher
>
> Book1, Book2, Book3...
>
> Video1, Video2, Video3...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your question pretty broad, but lets to clarify.

1) Shorty about view:

**Publisher** - CompositeView? It will be correct approach if you are going to render in this view PublisherModel or PublisherCollection. If this view just a wrap for child views, use LayoutView.

**Book List** - looks like you are going to render collection here, so you should use CollectionView or CompositeView instead ItemView. ItemView should be used in case you would like to render single model.

2) Common approach use separate request for each collection or model. In your case you should send request for video, another for books and so on. If you would like to get all data in one request u'd better to create something like Controller - it will be in charge to parse this request response and provide parsed data to special collections.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a great use case for [backbone-relational](http://backbonerelational.org/). In your server side code you define your json to contain nested elements. So each publisher would have a book list and a video list that's returned in the json. Then backbone-relational will auto-parse those and create collections/models for you. So you could say publisher.get('books') and you'd get your books collection. You also can get a reference from your books in your book list to your publisher and so on. I find it's a great way to just make the one call and handle all of the other pieces from there.

So your publisher model code would be something like this (note - your keys should actually match your json):

```
class Entities.Publisher extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    urlRoot: "publishers"

    relations: [
      {
      type: Backbone.HasMany
      key: "bookLists"
      relatedModel: Entities.BookList
      reverseRelation: 
        key: 'publisher'
        includeInJSON: 'id'
      },
      {
      type: Backbone.HasMany
      key: "videoLists"
      relatedModel: Entities.VideoList
      reverseRelation: 
        key: 'publisher'
        includeInJSON: 'id'
      }
    ]
```